# Issue while creating ORACLE_FDW extension

Tags: oracle11g, centos, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to install oracle_fdw on Cent OS 6.5

I have installed *.so as well as copies *.sql on correct places.

All the paths are properly set.

But when I make create extension command I am getting following error.
[image]